# Raphael JS: Odd behaviour with clicking/mousedown/dragging

Tags: click, raphael, element, transform

Hi I am currently working on a facebook app which incorporates Raphael JS. The user is able to click and drag geometric shapes around the canvas and the coordinates are then stored on an external database. For some reason on one machine, belonging to a colleague of mine, where each time the user interacts with the shapes, drawn using the Raphael js library, the element jumps to the top left of the canvas. On all other machines the element stays where it is when clicked and the user can drag the object around as expected.

Is there a reason for this? I have checked the developer log and there is nothing clearly wrong. There are no warnings or anything like that either. The only added library I am using is FreeTransform https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

Here is the code I am using the initialize my shapes. I am looping through a series of array items and producing a number of elements.

```
for (i in fb_circs){
    var s = paper.set();
    var c = paper.circle(fb_circs[i].x, fb_circs[i].y, fb_circs[i].r); c.title = fb_circs[i].id; c.p_set = s;
    var n = paper.circle(fb_circs[i].x, fb_circs[i].y, fb_circs[i].r); n.title = fb_circs[i].id; n.p_set = s;
    var l = paper.text(fb_circs[i].x, fb_circs[i].y, fb_circs[i].title.replace(/ /g,'\n')).attr({fill: fb_circs[i].tColour, 'font-size': fb_circs[i].font}); l.title = fb_circs[i].id; l.p_set = s;
    c.attr({"fill": fb_circs[i].f, "stroke": fb_circs[i].s, "stroke-width": fb_circs[i].swidth });
    n.attr({"fill": "#fff", 'fill-opacity': 0, 'opacity':0, "stroke": fb_circs[i].s, 'stroke-width':fb_circs[i].swidth });
    s.main_type = 'circle set';
    s.push(c); s.push(n); s.push(l);
    var f = paper.freeTransform(s, { keepRatio: true, drag: 'self', draw: [ 'bbox', 'circle' ] }, function(f, events){ });
    f.attrs.rotate = fb_circs[i].rotate; f.apply();

    f.setOpts({drag:'self', scale:false, rotate:false, draw:false}, function(f, events){
        var evt = String(events);
        if (evt.indexOf('end') == -1) return false;
        if (selected_circ == null) return false;
        if (!$('.colorpicker').is(':visible')) sets[selected_circ].last_rotate = f.attrs.rotate;
        if (editingCirc == 0) updateCirc(selected_circ);
    });

    s.id = fb_circs[i].id;
    s.primary_colour = fb_circs[i].f;
    s.t_colour = fb_circs[i].tColour;
    s.circ_title = fb_circs[i].title;
    s.stroke_colour = fb_circs[i].s;
    s.lastview = fb_circs[i].lastview;
    s.last_rotate = fb_circs[i].rotate;

    sets[s.id] = s;
    circs[s.id] = c;
    notifs[s.id] = n;
    lbls[s.id] = l;
    fts[s.id] = f;
    titles[s.id] = fb_circs[i].title;

    s.click(function(){ 
        if (editingCirc == 1){
            if (this.title != selected_circ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        selected_circ = this.title;         
        curr_type='1';
    });

    s.mousedown(function(){ 
        if (editingCirc == 1){
            if (this.title != selected_circ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        selected_circ = this.title;
        curr_type='1';
        sets[selected_circ].forEach(function (el){ el.node.ownerSVGElement.appendChild(el.node); }); 
    });

    s.hover( 
        function(){ 
            /* over */
            if (editingCirc == 1){
                if (this.title != selected_circ){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            curr_type='1';
            selected_circ = this.title;
            $('.popup_title').text(titles[this.title]);
            if (this.type!='text'){
                showPopup(this.getBBox());
            }
        }, 
        function(){ 
            /* out */
            //$('#tTip').fadeOut();
        }
    );

    s.drag( 
        function(){ 
            /* object moving */ 
            if (editingCirc == 1){
                if (this.title != selected_circ){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            showPopup( this.getBBox() ); 
        }, 
        function(){ 
            /* start drag */ 
        }, 
        function(){ 
            /* end drag */ 
        } 
    );
}
```

Comment: more details please; tested OS, tested browser vendors and versions, really, anything that can shed some light.

Comment: probably your dragging function relies on e.pageX / e.pageY which for example aren't available in Firefox. Please show a function used for dragging, how do you change object's position.

Comment: This only seems to be occurring on Chrome on Mac OS X on my colleagues machine. It works perfectly on the exact same setup on my machine however. It works well on Firefox on his machine, but not Chrome. There are no additional extensions on his Chrome install which could possibly be interfering either.

Comment: I've now tried this using a really old beat up DELL desktop machine with an old copy of FF on it and there was absolutely no problem, barring general performance issues i.e. speed. Is it possible that a single machine could experience issues with an interface which are simple unique to that machine?